# Writing to the serial port from the Linux command line

Tags: linux, serial-port, virtualbox

From Windows I can communicate with a serial port device using the following commands:

```
mode com1: baud=9600 data=8 parity=n stop=1
copy con com1
alt+18alt+2ctrl+z
```

The device starts the requested operation.

When I try to accomplish the same operation from a stand-alone [Debian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian) box or from a Debian [VirtualBox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox) instance of the same Windows machine, I had no luck so far.

Here are equivalent Linux commands (at least I think so):

```
stty -F /dev/ttyS0 speed 9600 cs8 -cstopb -parenb
echo '\x12\x02' > /dev/ttyS0
```

Nothing happens.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
echo '\x12\x02'
```

will not be interpreted, and will literally write the string `\x12\x02` (and append a newline) to the specified serial port.  Instead use

```
echo -n ^R^B
```

which you can construct on the command line by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>.  Or it is easier to use an editor to type into a script file.

The `stty` command should work, unless another program is interfering.  A common culprit is `gpsd` which looks for GPS devices being plugged in.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response, I tried the echo -n CTRL+VCTRL+RCTRRL+VCTRL+B from command line but I couldn't make it work, I want to try other commands, therefore I want to know how you come up with these translations(0x12 = ^R , 0x02 = ^B), these are not ascii translations I suppose.

Comment: @erincarikan:  use `man ascii` to see how 0x12 relates to Ctrl-R.  They are pure ascii.  It is possible that some ctrl combinations won't work, like ctrl-@ (NUL).   It could be easier to write a program to do a binary protocol like this.

Comment: thanks I totally got it, but unfortunately it doesn't work, I am suspecting that something is interfering with stty , I don't have gpsd running. I got to look into this more.

Comment: It finally worked, I had a problem in my virtualbox serial port configuation, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 36):

If you want to use hexadecimal codes, you should add the `-e` option to enable interpretation of backslash escapes by echo (but the result is the same as with `echo` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>). And as [wallyk said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8877269/writing-to-the-serial-port-from-the-linux-command-line/8877302#8877302), you probably want to add `-n` to prevent the output of a newline:

```
echo -en '\x12\x02' > /dev/ttyS0
```

Also make sure that `/dev/ttyS0` is the port you want.

Comment: thanks, I am sure that it is the port that I want, is there a simpler way of testing serial connection, echo always returns success.

Comment: If you're using `bash`, use `$''` quoting: `printf $'\x12\x02' >/dev/ttyS0`

Comment: How can I know to what port is connected my serial printer?

Answer (score 7):

#### Using [Screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen):

*Note*: Screen is actually not able to send hexadecimal, as far as I know.  To do that, use `echo` or `printf`.

I was using the suggestions in this post to write to a serial port, and then using the information from [another post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42376/reading-from-serial-from-linux-command-line) to read from the port, with mixed results.  I found that using Screen is an "easier" solution, since it opens a terminal session directly with that port. (I put easier in quotes, because Screen has a really weird interface, IMO, and takes some further reading to figure it out.)

You can issue this command to open a screen session, and then anything you type will be sent to the port, plus the return values will be printed below it:

```
screen /dev/ttyS0 19200,cs8
```

(Change the above to fit your needs for speed, parity, stop bits, etc.)  I realize Screen isn't the "Linux command line" as the post specifically asks for, but I think it's in the same spirit. Plus, you don't have to type echo and quotes every time.

#### echo

It follows [praetorian droid's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8877269/writing-to-the-serial-port-from-the-linux-command-line/8878504#8878504). *However*, this didn't work for me until I also used the *[cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix))* command  (`cat < /dev/ttyS0`) *while* I was sending the *echo* command.

#### printf

I found that one can also use printf's '%x' command:

```
c="\x"$(printf '%x' 0x12)
printf $c >> $SERIAL_COMM_PORT
```

Again, for printf, start `cat < /dev/ttyS0` before sending the command.

Comment: Nothing worked for me until I did as MrUser said: you have to be listening over /dev/ttyS0 before you can write to it.