# Linux Shell, How to send a command over Serial port and return?

Tags: linux, shell, serial-port

I am looking to send a 'reboot' command over the serial port to the PDU. What I have to do in the interactive mode is this:

```
#screen /dev/ttyS1
>reboot
>[Detach Screen]
#
```

If I want to automate this task in a script, I should be able to reboot the PDU with a single command from shell like this:

```
#echo "reboot" >/dev/ttyS1
```

However, it does not work ! I don't know why.... Would you be able to help me ?

The PDU manual request baud rate of 9600 which is not a default baud rate. I have tried following command to set the baud rate but still no lock:

```
stty -F /dev/ttyS1 speed 9600 cs8 -cstopb -parenb
```

These outputs does not change with or without screen:

```
 # stty -a -F /dev/ttyS1
    speed 9600 baud; rows 0; columns 0; line = 0;
    intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^H; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
    eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z;     rprnt = ^R;
    werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 100; time = 2;
    -parenb -parodd cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread clocal -crtscts
    -ignbrk brkint ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr -icrnl ixon    -ixoff
    -iuclc -ixany -imaxbel -iutf8
    -opost -olcuc -ocrnl -onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
    -isig -icanon iexten -echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
    echoctl echoke
```

Comment: I think this is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8877269/writing-to-serial-port-from-linux-command-line please have a look

Comment: @fvu that question was about sending \ char to the serial channel. I cannot send anything including \.

Comment: Okay, your edit shows that you already tried the stty bit :) You do realize that you run screen on /dev/ttyS1 and stty on /dev/ttyS0? Could you run  `stty -a -F /dev/ttyS1` on another console to see what settings screen is using? Contrast these with the settings the port has without screen running, it might give a clue as to one works and the other not.

Comment: That was a typo. No change when I run screen: `# stty -a -F /dev/ttyS1
   speed 9600 baud; rows 0; columns 0; line = 0;`

Comment: Better add both outputs of stty to your question

Comment: @fvu, just did that...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79979/discussion-between-fvu-and-arh).

Comment: If you're looking for something a little more robust (though less scriptable without Expect), you could try connecting to your device using `minicom`, `picocom`, or even `screen`.

Comment: @EricDand thanks for the tip. I think the existing solution is good for now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how we fixed this issue:

1. Config serial port with RAW setting:

   ```
   stty -F /dev/ttyS1 speed 9600 cs8 -cstopb -parenb raw
   ```
2. Send Command using echo with \r:

   ```
   echo -ne "reboot\r" > /dev/ttyS1
   ```

I believe that the above might include a typo. If the above doesn't work, try:

```
 echo -ne "reboot\n\r" > /dev/ttyS1
```