# Linux command to send data to a remote tcp-client

Tags: linux

I have a Linux Server running Redhat Rhel 7 and a Device called "Compoint Lan System (Colas)" (german manufacturer). The Colas has its own firmware so I don't know if it's based on linux. The Colas is set as a TCP-Client. It receives messages from its serial 1 port. I get the messages coming from the serial port 1 of the colas on my server with rsyslog.

Now what I want is to send a string (2 letters) from my server (tcp-server) to my colas's serial port 1 (tcp-client) to get information of the device attached to serial port 1.

Is there a command in linux to accomplish that? Something like "command 'string message' destination port"? I am sorry if it isn't written well.

Comment: Check netcat or telnet. Both of these tools can send raw TCP data. There may be other tools as well that can be used. Personally I would write a small python script for this as basic TCP handling can be done very quickly. For more information check [Python socket docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html)

Comment: Sounds like you want to write to a serial port, not a tcp port?  Maybe check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8877269/writing-to-serial-port-from-linux-command-line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install netcat

```
yum install nc
```

Make it to listen to a particular port number

```
nc –l portnumber &
```

Lets validate it using netstat from a different console:

```
netstat -anlp |grep yourportnumber
```

PS: Change the installation command based on your linux flavor.

Comment: That's not what i wanted. I don't want to listen to the incoming data of my colas-device I want to send two letters / characters to the from my server to the device. Imagined it in a different way: The device attached to the colas-device is sending special letters. I need to send a special string to this device to get the systemstatus of it.

For example: I receive the letters "a" and "b" and I need to send the letter "c" in order to get system information from it

Comment: It does what it says. It can listen to anything that you wish to pass. I am not sure which part is unclear for you to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Ranadip Dutta's answer meets your requirement. The *listen* there doesn't mean *listen for incoming data*, it rather means *listen for connection request from client*. Of course you can't use `rsyslog` and `nc` as the server at the same time, but with `nc` you get the messages coming from the Colas displayed as well as the characters you enter sent.

Comment: But it doesn't actually tell me how to send a string like letters to the Colas which I want to do. So I don't understand it at all.

Comment: @SchnoppDog - To _send a string like letters to the Colas_, you'd just enter it as input to `nc`.

Comment: Ok, after short googling I found some examples. Sorry that I am bad at understanding. You helped me with your answer.

Comment: Is there a option which I can use to "delete" listen on a port? Because when I try to bind a text file onto the port with  " <pre> nc -l 8080 > listen.txt <code>" there is a message telling me <pre> ncat bind to 8080: Address already in use QUITTING <code>

Comment: @SchnoppDog - An _option_ to which program do you mean? Of course _listen_ is _deleted_ if the listening process terminates.